# Can't create unsigned column in Laravel 7

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-7

I am building management application using laravel. I am trying to create the tables 'role_user' in laravel, but when I run the 'php artisan migrate' command, I get the following:  BadMethodCallException
Method Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint::name does not exist. Can anyone tell what do you mean by this error?

```
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class CreateRolesTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('roles', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->name();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

but if i tring to migrate that i see

```
λ php artisan migrate
Migrating: 2020_06_07_055653_create_roles_table

   BadMethodCallException

  Method Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint::name does not exist.

  at E:\laragon\www\os\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Support\Traits\Macroable.php:103
     99|      */
    100|     public function __call($method, $parameters)
    101|     {
    102|         if (! static::hasMacro($method)) {
  > 103|             throw new BadMethodCallException(sprintf(
    104|                 'Method %s::%s does not exist.', static::class, $method
    105|             ));
    106|         }
    107|

  • Bad Method Call: Did you mean Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint::rename() ?

  1   E:\laragon\www\os\database\migrations\2020_06_07_055653_create_roles_table.php:18
      Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint::__call("name", [])

  2   E:\laragon\www\os\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Schema\Builder.php:166
      CreateRolesTable::{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint))
```

Comment: I am pretty user you do not need $table->id(); call

Comment: ok, i deleted $table->id();  but still have that issue

Comment: This is not the correct migration file, the class of the file is `CreateRoleUserTable`, so your migration file is named `create_role_user_table`, and your error is from `create_roles_table`

Comment: Thanx, fix that.

Comment: `$table->name();` doesn't exist, it's probably `$table->string('name');` https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/migrations#creating-columns

Comment: THANK YOU, @kerbh0lz, you solve my problem!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead:

```
$table->name();
```

It supposed to be:

```
$table->string('name', 32); // change 32 to max length
```

Why?

There is no "name" [type](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_datatypes.asp) in MySQL (or any other DB engine). You probably was misleaded because of `->id()` or `->timestamps()`. Also there is no "id" column type, but this works because in Laravel this was made as shortcut (because it is often used).

So there is no difference if you use:

```
$table->id().
$table->timestamps();
```

Or

```
$table->bigIncrements('id');
$table->timestamp('created_at', $precision)->nullable();
$table->timestamp('updated_at', $precision)->nullable();
```

Because it is doing same thing under hood anyway.

[Read more in docs](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/migrations#creating-columns).

Answer (score 0):

You can change your code to :

```
    Schema::create('roles', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->string('name');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
$table->id()
```

to

```
$table->bigIncrements('id');
```